# Is it a problem if the framing is 4" short of the edge of slab foundation?

Tags: framing, foundation

Addition to house, added slab to 7.5' x 21' porch surrounded on 3 sides.  Brick & siding exterior.  I think the framers thought there was going to be continuous brick, because the framing is set back about 3"-4" from edge of slab, but siding was put in there & so exterior of house is set back from edge of slab now.  Am concerned about water getting into house from exposed slab.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If when everything is done, the slab will have an exposed horizontal surface, then yes, that is incorrect. Either the plans were drawn incorrectly, or someone didn't follow them. Whoever made the mistake should be responsible to fix it.

At this point, your options are to rip down the wall and fix it, double the thickness of the wall (weird) or remove the bottom row of siding and install flashing.

Comment: Tearing down the whole wall seems excessive. At worst I would think you could remove the siding and add some 2x4 as oversized furring strips. Depending on the climate you might take advantage of the extra space to add more insulation.

Comment: Well yeah, duh, tearing down the wall is excessive. My point was to list the options. And I suggested doubling the thickness of the wall (2x4 as oversized furring strips).

Comment: What did you do about this? We are in a 47-year-old tract house on a slab which has 10 ft of siding with a 6" wide shelf of concrete projecting out from the siding.  It could be that the foundation contractor thought that this wall was to be brick like most of the rest of the house. Someone suggested to me that concrete was added to cover a "blowout" of concrete under the pouring form. The added concrete is angled down from the siding to the outside so water drains off. The lower courses of siding there rotted due to wetting from a sprinkler head, and I replaced them. The sill was sound.